# Given a list with dictionary as its elements we have link dictionary element with their corresponding index

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

```
li=[{'mic': 1, 'ric': 1, 'vic': 1, 'nic': 1},{'adam': 1, 'brick': 1, 'mik': 1},{'patel': 1, 'np': 1, 'rg': 1, 'tony': 1}#Here we have to link dictionary element to their next index element n= len(li) 
for i in range(n):
    if(i==0):

Output li=[{'mic': 1, 'aa': 1, 'bb': 1, 'cc':1,'next_mic=adam':1},{'adam': 1, 'dd': 1, 'ee': 1,'next_adam=patel':1,'prev_adam=mic':1}{'patel': 1, 'ff': 1, 'gg': 1, 'hh': 1,'prev_patel=adam':1}]
```

Comment: It is unclear what you aim to achieve and the question body does not make much sense: it is invalid code.

Comment: I am trying to connect li[0]['mic'] to li[1]['adam'

Comment: what do you mean with "connect"?

Comment: means {'mic':1,'next_mic=adam':1} and {'adam':1,'prev_adam=mic':1}